# CSS animation Image from small to bigger and center

Tags: css

i have been struggle for animate this image bigger and to centering.

look at this video for sure, it's only 9 seconds.

https://youtu.be/b-5KPH_RGIg

and this is the action

https://jsfiddle.net/09b74624/1/

i'm using :

```
.biggerCenter {transform:scale(0.1); transition:transform 0.5s linear; }
.biggerCenter:hover { transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1); }
```

how to get this thing done?

what's wrong with my code?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translation does not leave enough space on the sides. Assuming your picture gets 50%, it will need 25% on each side.
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/09b74624/5/) is a working fiddle based on your example.

```
.biggerCenter:hover
{
  transform:translate(+25%, +25%) scale(1);
}
```

Also, I would recommend you using a nice plugin.
[Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) does what you need.

Comment: what if the image was 200px x 200px, how many translate should i use? how to calculate it?

Comment: Question. You want every picture to get a specific width/height when rescaled?

Comment: yeah, basiclly. the main picture was 200px x 200px, i want to scale + translate it to the center. how to calculate those math?

Comment: Scale to what, how much, what is max W/H?... Calculate using math.

Comment: I added you a working code, test it on whatever you need and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you, @ChingChing :). Using plugins makes your life easier. It's a good way to go using plugins, because it makes things easier. However, I do not recommend you using them while learning.